# ¿Saben cuantas peticiones gratuitas al dia se pueden realizar a la Distance Matrix API?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Hola buenas tardes a todos, estoy desarrollando un proyecto de optimización de rutas de RSU, y necesito obtener la matriz de distancias de los puntos que agrega el usuario al mapa, he leído la documentación de la Distance Matrix API en cuanto a peticiones por día pero no me queda muy clara, alguien podria ayudarme solo necesito saber cuantas peticiones puedo realizar al servicio al dia.

(Llámese peticiones al link que consultó para obtener la respuesta JSON).

De ante mano muchas gracias, espero y alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parece que cambiaron la modalidad de pago y ahora te cobran por la cantidad de request's que le haces a la API. Cuantos más pedidos, más pagas, osea que ya no hay límites, sino que el límite es lo que quieras pagar.

> As of July 16, 2018, to continue to use the Google Maps Platform APIs,
>   you must enable billing on each of your projects. If you choose not to
>   add a billing account, your maps will be degraded, or other Maps API
>   requests will return an error.

Osea que desde Julio del 2018 si no estás suscripto a la API con tu dirección de pago los pedidos a la API te van a devolver un error!

**PRECIOS**

0–100,000 ---> 0.005 USD per each
(5.00 USD per 1000)

100,001–500,000 ---> 0.004 USD per each
(4.00 USD per 1000)

Más info:

[Documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing)

Comment: Muchas gracias Nacho de la torre he leido más a fondo la documentación y encontre una calculadora de precios y encontré que Google te da un crédito equivalente a $200 por mes mientras no superes ese crédito las peticiones se harán normalmente

Comment: De nada Juan ! Si te sirvió la respuesta recuerda marcarla como aceptada así nos dan puntos a ambos y también ayuda a otros de la comunidad a encontrarlas más facilmente. Salu2